# Will I get the bounty?

Tags: support

I posted this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270540/why-do-they-swap-hats-in-andor), and it was received negatively, but there is as a 500 bounty on it.

So will I despite the negative 4 downvotes receive the bounty at the end of the grace period??

Comment: Only Schwern can answer that definitively. But very likely no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, your answer must be the highest scoring since the bounty was posted with at least a score of 2, from [the help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), **the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount** (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Unless of course the user who set the bounty decides to manually award it to you.